# Propel multiple-parameter binding in where() clause

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

I'm trying to run this query on Propel 1.6 with symfony 1.4.20.

I want to bind 2 parameters onto this subquery but its not working.

```
$paginas = PaginaQuery::create()                              
                               ->where("pagina.id not in (select id from cliente_artista where cliente_artista.cliente_id = ? and cliente_artista.culture = ?)"
                                       ,array('XXX', 'en')
                                      )
                          ->limit(5)
                          ->find();
```

This gives me the error:

```
Cannot determine the column to bind to the parameter in clause
```

I also found this post but there is no answer (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/propel-users/2Ge8EsTgoBg)

Comment: I don't have time to write this up as an answer, but you should look at the [documentation for subqueries](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#using-a-query-as-input-for-a-second-query-table-su) which I think will let you do this in one DB hit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using placeholders. You may use $id and $culture:

```
//first, get an array of the id's
//define your vars
$id = $your_id_param;
$culture = 'en';
$cliente_artistas = ClienteArtistaQuery::create()
                        ->select('id')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->filterByClienteId($id)
                        ->filterByCulture($culture)
                        ->find();

$paginas = PaginaQuery::create()                              
               ->where("pagina.id NOT IN ?", $cliente_artistas)
               ->limit(5)
               ->find();
```

If this has to be done in one query, recommend using raw sql and binding the parameters into the PDO statement (but then you lose the convenience of PropelObjectCollections):

```
  public function getResultSet($id, $culture) {
    $id = $id_param;
    $culture = $culture_param;
    $sql = <<<ENDSQL
SELECT * from pagina
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT distinct id 
                 FROM cliente_artista 
                 WHERE cliente_id = ?
                 AND culture = ?
                 )
LIMIT 5
ENDSQL;
    $connection = Propel::getConnection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(1, $id);
    $statement->bindValue(2, $culture);
    $statement->execute();
    $resultset = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // or whatever you need

    if (! count($resultset) >= 1) {
      // Handle empty resultset
    }

    return $resultset;
  }
```

You could also write some query methods to use [propel orm query methods](http://propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#using-a-query-as-input-for-a-second-query-table-su). Ofcourse, the [propel api](http://api.propelorm.org/1.6.8/) is beneficial reference. There are several ways to do this. I have indicated one method here which should work for you.

**EDIT:**
Here's an idea on doing this as one query [since useSelectQuery() requires 'relation' name], this idea assumes tables are not related but that id's are:

```
$paginas = PaginaQuery::create()                              
           ->addJoin(PaginaPeer::ID, ClienteArtistaPeer::CLIENTE_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN)
           ->where("ClienteArtista.Id <> ?", $id)
           ->where("ClienteArtista.Culture <> ?", $culture)
           ->select(array('your','pagina','column','array'))
           ->limit(5)
           ->find();
```

Comment: The problem there is that you have to do two DB hits. See my comment on the OP issue with reference to some documentation (no time to write up an example write now).

Comment: There's a link in my other comment (on the original issue), or just search the Propel docs for "subqueries".

Comment: jakarella, i've read the documentation for subqueries, but i still dont know how to use the addSelectQuery within a NOT IN condition. @Qoheleth-Tech, i tried your first solution but i still having the same error. i checked that i'm using the propel 1.6.3. i'll update it right now and come back here to update.

Comment: @Pedro, Try first method again; replace where("pagina.id..." with where("Pagina.Id...", I confirmed this method takes Propelized Names [sorry, that was part of the error all along]. Second, you might need to take $cliente_artistas (a PropelArrayCollection) and say $cliente_artistas->getArrayCopy() or perhaps use an offset (i.e., $cliente_artistas[0]) if that doesn't do it right away, but to my recollection the PropelArrayCollection should work in that criteria without any additional selector helps, because you are selecting only one column. [Propel 1.6.3 api](api.propelorm.org/1.6.3).

Comment: @Qoheleth-Tech i got it! i had to use ->select(ClienteArtistaPeer::ARTISTA_PAGINA_ID) and didnt need the getArrayCopy. I just passed the PropelArrayCollection with the only one column. But i think we are running onto a problem here, as im not using a subquery. MySQL has a limit for the NOT IN condition (i dont know this number, i think its 1000) and my query now has it: not in ('6','111','118'). i can have problems with a big NOT IN condition and im also doing 2 databases HITs. any suggestion of doing this with subquery? I can try the second option u mentioned and im pretty sure that will work

Comment: @Pedro, I didn't think about how big your resultset would be. Let me know if the single query works for you. Thanks.

Comment: im pretty sure that we can solve this problem using joins, your last example is quite correct.. the problem is that the join returns duplicated lines (ive tried inner,left and right) and the distinct mess the data. ill try some group by